# Is it possible to convert ColorStateList to Drawable

Tags: android, android-drawable

I'm trying to pass in a ColorStateList into a View to set it as the background, and I'm passing it as a reference. However, after getting the ColorStateList from the reference, I'm not sure how to set it as the background of the view.

The below code doesn't work.

Attribute definition:

```
    <attr name="tabBackgroundColor" format="reference" />
```

Attribute reference in the app:

```
    app:tabBackgroundColor="@color/tab_background_colors"
```

Attempting to get the ColorStateList as a drawable and set it.

```
    tabView.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), mTabBackgroundColor));
```

Exception when above code is run

```
    Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable ols.microsoft.com.sampleapp:color/tab_background_colors with resource ID #0x7f0d0067
                                                                          Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/color/tab_background_colors.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0d0067
```

Comment: It is possible, show me your xml code

Comment: I'm trying to set it programatically. I've included a few more lines above. Will keep adding more if it helps.

Comment: Actually, idk why I wasn't just passing in a drawable.

Comment: Passing in a drawable I still get the ResourceNotFoundException. Will continue to investigate. Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable ols.microsoft.com.sampleapp:drawable/tab_background with resource ID #0x7f020068
                                                                            Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/tab_background.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020068

Comment: Add code where mTabBackgroundColor is instatiate and tab_background_colors is defined, because its certainly cause of your problem.

Comment: @fobbymaster hey, did you managed to find the answer? Same problem

Comment: @AntonShkurenko Looking at the code now, I can't seem to find it. BUT I think I remember that the issue was that the resource I was passing in was a color file and not a drawable xml.